# Read large file in C++

Tags: c++, fread

I manage a PDF file whose size is 2.15GB, I opened the file with fopen, I use `_fseeki64` and `_ftelli64` in order to get or update the pointer position in the file and it works correctly.

I use `fread` in order to read from the pdf file. Usually it works properly, but when the read pointer is located near to the end of the file, `fread` get the EOF character which is wrong.

So, how can I read correctly from this large PDF file.

NB: I use the same source code with file whose size is less than 2GB and it works correctly.

Comment: Can you reduce the code to a short program that reliably demonstrates the problem? Until you do, no one can help, since there is no knowing what you do wrong.

Comment: " when the read pointer is located near to the end of the file, fread get the EOF character which is wrong" - can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Can you guarantee that the process is not running out of available memory while reading in the file?

Comment: What platform are you using? What large file compiler options of #define's are you using?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz `_fseeki64` seems to be Windows-only

Comment: `fread` receives `size_t`, so if `size_t` is 32 bits then it probably won't work with large files

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: size_t won't be an issue while working with file of size 2.15GB on 32 bit system.

Comment: @sameerkn some personal code may use that as a signed type without noticing

Comment: Your question would do well to include some example code that exhibits the problem and to specify the compiler used and target OS.  Everything that would enable a third-party to reproduce the problem in fact.

Comment: @sameerkn and it happens even in proper code but buggy compiler/stdlib, like you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16325024/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me that your're seeing the 2G limit of a signed 32-bit integer. The maximum value of such a variable is 2,147,483,647.

**Edit**

Use a debugger and check the *actual value and type* sent to `_fseeki64`and `_ftelli64`.

Answer (score 0):

With a modern compiler (VS2012+ on Windows) you can use `fstream` which is the standard way to access large files.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16325024/342) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned things like EOF, so please check if you are using fread properly. Most importantly the loop if its there in which you try to read data in chunks.

Please check if you are not a victim of [Wrongly using loop while using fread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

There is no matter with the fread function, But, the read pointer of the file was already located at the end of the file. That's why it return EOF.
When I change the read pointer position, fread works properly.

Comment: This information should be added to your question by editing it not posted as an *answer* - SO is not a discussion forum.