# the program should display the last 5 lines of the file, but it does not work with large files

Tags: c++, linux

I wrote a program that should print the last 5 lines of a file, but the teacher created a file with a line of 4 GB, and the program broke. How to rewrite a program so that it can work with very large files

a possible solution is to read the file character by character, but I don’t know how to do it

here is the c ++ program code

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

#include <string>

using std::ifstream;
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::getline;

int main(int argc, char * argv[], char * env[]) {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  int i;
  string line;

  if (argc == 3) {

    string filename = argv[1];

    ifstream myfile(filename);
    string n = argv[2];

    int nn = atoi(n.c_str());

    string line, buffer[nn];
    const size_t size = sizeof buffer / sizeof * buffer;
    size_t i = 0;

    while (getline(myfile, line)) {
      buffer[i] = line;
      if (++i >= size) {
        i = 0;
      }
    }

    for (size_t j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
      cout << buffer[i] << "\n";
      if (++i >= size) {
        i = 0;
      }
    }
    //return 0;

  }

}
```

Comment: Start from describing what it supposed to do (it is not pleasant to figure out this from badly written code even when it is small). And it looks like that it is buggy.

Comment: `buffer[nn];` - don't use variable length arrays.

Comment: buffer[nn] this is the number of lines displayed

Comment: What do you mean by "the program broke" ? Describe exactly what went wrong, and what you expected instead. Also describe the contents of the 4GB input file (how many lines, maximum line length, etc.).

Comment: Besides, why not simply using `const size_t size = nn;` ?

Comment: Related, C++ does not limit the file size: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324811/ifstream-what-is-the-maximum-file-size-that-a-ifstream-can-read

Comment: If you are supposed to display just last 5 lines, you don't need to store all the file contents in memory. Store just 5 last-read lines and display them at the end.

Comment: what's `sizeof buffer`? it's the second time i saw it today in two different questions....

Comment: Is this some assignment, where you are not allowed to use certain library classes or can you use STL?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously broken here, ugly though it may be. Time to stop staring at the code and fire up an actual debugger!

Comment: What is the meaning of the two argument the parameter uses? The first one is the file name, the second the number of lines to read?

Comment: @Federico https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

Comment: My observations (not related to the problem): `int i` and `string line` defined on top are not used and get shadowed inside conditional. `size` is simply the value of `nn`. variable sized array allocation is wrong.

Comment: Quick solution: recompile in 64-bit :) Though the assignment is stupid. No text file contains such long lines.

Comment: Where is 5? Is it supposed to be a program argument?

Comment: Could you please check if that 4GB file has one or more long lines, like lines of 1GB?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6039648/12149686

Comment: Have you found the issue or solution, yet?

Answer (score 3):

The problem must be with big lines in that 4GB file. Your solution buffers (and later drops) every line and at least one of the lines is probably too long to be buffered in the machine you're running, making your program crash.

You should read the file starting from the end counting the number of newlines and stop and output the rest of if when you reach the count of `nn + 1`. Buffering the last `nn` lines is not a good option when you need to handle big lines.

Here a snippet of a solution that could help you:

```
array<char, 64 * 1024> buffer; // 64kb of buffer

size_t nn = atoi(n.c_str()); 

myfile.seekg(0, ios_base::end); 

unsigned int nlcount = 0; 
size_t length = myfile.tellg(); 
size_t oldpos = length; 

while (myfile.tellg() > 0) { 
  size_t newpos = oldpos - min(oldpos, buffer.size()); 
  myfile.seekg(newpos); 
  size_t rdsize = oldpos - newpos; 
  myfile.read(buffer.data(), rdsize); 
  if (!myfile) { 
    cerr << "failed while looking for newlines\n"; 
    return 1; 
  } 
  auto rit = buffer.rbegin() + (buffer.size() - rdsize); 
  while (rit != buffer.rend() && nlcount <= nn) { 
    if (*rit == '\n') { 
      ++nlcount; 
    } 
    ++rit; 
  } 
  if (nlcount > nn) { 
    myfile.seekg(newpos + (buffer.rend() - rit) + 1); 
    break; 
  } 
  oldpos = newpos; 
}
```

This will point the input stream to the exact position where you just need to output the rest of it *if `nlcount` is equal to `nn + 1`*. I recommend you to output it not using buffered lines, but using a fixed sized buffer:

```
while (myfile.peek() != EOF) {
  myfile.read(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
  cout.write(buffer.data(), myfile.gcount());
}
```

Don't use `getline()` or you will still end up buffering lines and crash when handling long ones.

Comment: The described problem has nothing to do with long lines so there is no problem with using `getline()`

Comment: Because it is not in the question. You are suppose to answer the question not your assumptions.

Comment: I am not saying you are wrong, I am just saying don't be sure and advise based on your assumption. Also you did not provide a source of why you are saying `getline()` will fail and what is the limit for using it. "problem reading the long lines file"  is very general and should not be used as answer.

Answer (score -1):

To remove buffer dependency one way is to read the file from the end backward to reach the number of lines you want. 5 is hard-coded here but you can pass it as a parameter.

```
std::ifstream fileReader("test.txt", std::ios_base::ate );
std::string currentLine;
long length;
int lines;
char c = '\0';

if( fileReader )
{
    length = fileReader.tellg();
    for(long i = length-2; i > 0; i-- )
    {
        fileReader.seekg(i);
        c = fileReader.get();
        if( c == '\r' || c == '\n' )
        {
            lines++;
            if (lines == 5)
                break;
        }
    }

    while(fileReader)
    {
        std::getline(fileReader, currentLine);
        std::cout << currentLine << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: @FernandoSilveira I have test it on 4GB file and it was OK. Also it does not have any explicit array for buffering.

Comment: @FernandoSilveira "4GB file" not "4GB line". Read the question carefully.

Comment: You assume too much ;)

Comment: Some of my comments are being removed (not by me), so I'll just go ahead and remove them all.

Comment: This doesn't work if the input contains any `'\r'` that are not part of a crlf. And it will also break down on very long lines.